# Setting an order minimum for my Bigcartel store?

Tags: bigcartel

I've been searching Google all day for code that will prevent customers from being able to checkout until a minimum cart total is reached. If anyone can be of assistance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Would you be willing to show what you've tried? And maybe specify a bit about what languages/technologies you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to try anything. I have not found any HTML or CSS coding to do what I need.

Comment: I found a plugin through Wordpress which is exactly what I need but I don't know how to make it work for me in Bigcartel: https://wordpress.org/plugins/edd-prevent-checkout/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Cart page in Customize Design > Advanced > Cart. Find the code for the Checkout button at the bottom of the page, and replace it with this:

```
{% if cart.total > 500 %}
  <button id="checkout-btn" class="button" type="submit" title="Checkout">Checkout</button>
{% else %}
  You must have at least $500 in your cart to checkout.
{% endif %}
```

The exact code for the button will depend on your theme, but this should give you a good start.

Comment: Nick, it worked!!! Thank you so very much. I owe you a cupcake jar. Seriously. Pick a flavor and you can email your info to me (luvbakes@gmail.com). I'll ship it on Monday :)